# What's wrong with this code?. I just learned programming a few minutes ago and I'm trying to make this

Tags: c++, c

I just learned programming a few minutes ago and I'm trying to make this

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int n, fibo_n, fibo_n1=1, fibo_n2=0
    cout<<"Enter the max term of the Fibonacci Sequence: "

    for (int i =1; i<n; i++){
        fibo_n=fibo_n1+fibo_n2
        fibo_n2=fibo_n1
        fibo_n1=fibo_n
        cout<<fibo_n<<" "
    }
    cout<<endl
    cin.get()
    return 0
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d\n", &fib0, &fib1);` makes pointers from ints. Just print the ints without `&`. `scanf` needs a `&` because you really want a reference to `N`.

Comment: What's your input, your expected output and actual output? Aka "random numbers"

Comment: the posted code is C++ not C  Please correct the 'tags' list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code one is you are printing addresses of fib0,  fib1 instead of their value and the second is you are using only one format specifier while printing two values.

Here is the modified code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Fibonaci(int N);

void main(){
    int N;
    long hasil;
    printf("Enter the number of elements : ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    Fibonaci(N);
 }
void Fibonaci(int N){
    int fib0=0, fib1=1, fib;
    printf("%d\n%d\n", fib0, fib1); //modified
    while(fib0<=N/2){
        fib=fib0+fib1;
        fib0=fib1;
        fib1=fib;
        printf("\n%d", fib1); //modified
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel Thanks, I have modified my answer.

Comment: Note that when notifying people with the `@` syntax in comments, spaces in the person's username should be omitted. This is done automatically when using the autocomplete feature (TAB key). When writing a comment, you can press the "Help" button to read more about this.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Fibonaci(int N);

void main(){
    int N;
    long hasil;
    printf("Enter the number of elements : ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    Fibonaci(N);
}
void Fibonaci(int N){
    int fib0=0, fib1=1, fib;
    printf("%d, %d\n", fib0, fib1);
    while(fib0<=N/2){
        fib=fib0+fib1;
        fib0=fib1;
        fib1=fib;
        printf("\n%d", fib1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of simply providing a code-only answer, you may also want to explain a bit what was wrong.